# Creating CodeMemberMethod from string

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I am trying to generate some code using CodeDom. I wanted to know if there is any way to create CodeMemberMethod from a string.
I found a method, but it generates assembly from string. I wanted to generate some methods from string. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. Hope it may help someone else:

We can use `CodeSnippetStatement` to include code fragments that will be included directly in source without modification.

In addition to that, there is `CodeSnippetCompileUnit` that will compile code units from string literal.